# Copy data from Spreadsheet[LibreOffice Calc] to tables of Text Document[LibreOffice]

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

This was very interesting and challenging task for me. I want to copy data (1000s of rows with multiple columns) from Libre Office calc[spreadsheet] to the tables in Libre Office Writer[Text Document]. I spent almost a day to figure out the solution. Couldn't find the solution from any sites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the data[rows] from Spreadsheet.
2. Paste the same to the MS Word document[I did it by using Google docs as  I'm using ubuntu].The table is created with rows and columns which is same as copied data.
3. Copy the table from word document and paste it in the Libre office Text Document.
4. Create the table with number of rows and columns Libre office Text Document.
5. Copy the table from Libre office Text Document[copied in point(3)] and paste in the table which is created in point(4).

**NOTE / CAUTION** : If you skip or alter any steps, it wont work.

Comment: Yes its different. It will not be fit in pre cretaed table. It ll be copied to single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a column of text (perhaps from a screen-scrape of a online table) to a table format suitable for further work in a spreadsheet is easy if you have the traditional (locally installed) MS-Word program.  The "Convert text to table" function there permits you to specify how many columns are in each record without having to edit your input files to manually place delimiters like commas, semi-colons, tabs etc. which is a PITA when you have to count rows to leave out the delimiter.

LibreOffice writer has a lightweight convert-text-to-table function which requires a lot of data conditioning before using it.  In Libra Calc, Like any good spreadsheet, the "Transpose" function can be used to convert, say, 8 rows of the input column to a single 8-column row, but automating this requires macros or fixed templates.

So it is a non-trivial problem to duplicate that powerful capability in the old, locally installed MS-Word app, where users can take pages and pages of one-word data elements, and convert them into a "N" column table, where "N" is specified when you invoke the conversion in MS Word.